# Align span class using table

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

I have a span class output below which I need to integrate into a table. How can I use table "tr" "td" with the span class below ?

```
table <tr> <td>


 <?php
include_once('database_conn.php');
$sqlCDs = 'SELECT CDID, CDTitle, CDYear, catDesc, CDPrice FROM nmc_cd b inner join nmc_category c on b.catID = c.catID WHERE 1 order by CDTitle';
$rsCDs = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCDs);
while ($CD = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsCDs)) {
        echo "\t<div class='item'>
            <span class='CDTitle'>{$CD['CDTitle']}</span>
            <span class='CDYear'>{$CD['CDYear']}</span>
            <span class='catDesc'>{$CD['catDesc']}</span>
            <span class='CDPrice'>{$CD['CDPrice']}</span>
            <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' value='{$CD['CDID']}' title='{$CD['CDPrice']}' onchange='isChecked();' onclick='getTotalsum()'/></span>
        </div>\n";
}
?>
```

Sample:

```
echo "<tr><td>";
                echo "Column1";
                echo "</td><td>";  
                echo "Column2";
                echo "</td><td>";  
                echo "Column3";
                echo "</td><td>";  
                echo "Column4";
                echo "</TD></tr>";
```

Comment: What you mean by 'integrate into a table'?

Comment: What you need is to inject your generated code into a <td>? What final code should looks like?

Comment: @romuleald yes correct, just like the sample i have above which i usually do for <div> but i'm trying to figure our for <span class>

Comment: Why don't you wrap your lines with tr/td?

Answer (score 1):

To display:

- multiple CD data as columns, each CD having its own row
- all enclosed in a proper table
- if no results, safely render nothing

Try:

```
<?php
include_once('database_conn.php');

$sqlCDs = 'SELECT CDID, CDTitle, CDYear, catDesc, CDPrice FROM nmc_cd b inner join nmc_category c on b.catID = c.catID WHERE 1 order by CDTitle';

if ($rsCDs = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCDs)) {

    // HTML table start
    echo "<table>";

    // table head
    echo "\t<thead><tr>
        <th>CD Title</th>
        <th>CD Year</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Chosen</th>
        </tr></thead>";

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($CD = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsCDs)) {

        echo "\t<tr>
                <td class='CDTitle'>{$CD['CDTitle']}</td>
                <td class='CDYear'>{$CD['CDYear']}</td>
                <td class='catDesc'>{$CD['catDesc']}</td>
                <td class='CDPrice'>{$CD['CDPrice']}</td>
                <td class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' value='{$CD['CDID']}' title='{$CD['CDPrice']}' onchange='isChecked();' onclick='getTotalsum()'/></td>
                </tr>\n";

    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($rsCDs);

    // HTML table close
    echo "</table>\n";

}
?>
```

Here are the changes explained:

### PHP logic

Assuming your original MySQL and SQL query works, only some slight changes are needed to make it work, most of it is your original code.

The main change in the code logic was handling what happens when there are no SQL results.

In your your original code with `<divs>` and `<spans>`, you already had this working fine:

- if there are results then multiple `<divs>` with `<spans>` within, will render, which is fine
- if there are no results then no `<divs>` nor `<spans>` render, which is fine

However the example PHP code seems:

- if there are results then it starts to render `<table>` and the multiple records starting with `<tr><td>...`
- if there are no results then it still starts to render `<table>` just with no records inside

This is because the example PHP code you included, seems to put HTML table first before any PHP checks whether there is a SQL result, thus when there is a SQL result it renders the rest of the table so that case is fine, but when there is no SQL result you end up with HTML table being started but not finished, thus you risk ending up with incomplete/broken HTML

So to fix this, we introduce the `if (` statement in order to check for us, if there is a SQL result, and only if there is a SQL result, then start to render the HTML table. So if there is no result, then, just as your original code with `<div>`s and `<spans>` did, it should safely render nothing.

The `mysqli_free_result($rsCDs);` is to free up resources.

PHP logic restructure based on *Example #2 Procedural style* from [mysqli_result::fetch_assoc documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

### HTML

The code chunk beginning with `// table head`  is just to introduce HTML column headings. This is optional, you can remove this if you prefer no headings.

The `</table>` is to close the HTML table properly.

### Additional notes

After you test this code, remember it only takes care of the HTML table and PHP aspects, but HTML may affect your CSS and JavaScript so you may have to spend some time to check and adjust CSS and your JavaScript to work with the new HTML.